# Treesitter text-object to capture jupyter cell expression #%%

Tags: neovim, treesitter

can a neovim guru help create a treesitter query which matches '#%%' pattern in python files?

I use `#%%` inside my python files to quickly jump between code blocks. It also helps if i convert the .py file to .ipynb, in that it uses the ``#%%``` string to define cell boundaries in jupyter.

I will be grateful if someone can  help create a tree-sitter text query which recognises this pattern and a keymapping to help me jump from one occurence of ``#%%``` to next (and backwards)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you require Treesitter? Or, would you like a solution that makes use of the built-in forward and backward search? Using Treesitter's syntax trees seems excessive for this problem

Answer (score 1):

This does the needful:

```s
((comment) @cell.boundary
  (#eq? @cell.boundary "# %%"))
```

To get next/prev key-mappings you can install the [nvim-treesitter-textobjects](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects) plugin and configure its `move` capability to map your desired keystrokes to this `@cell.boundary` capture.

That would look something like:

```
textobjects = {
  move = {
    enable = true,
    goto_next_start = {
      ["]c"] = "@cell.boundary",
    },
    goto_previous_start = {
      ["[c"] = "@cell.boundary",
    },
  },
```

in the nvim-treesitter configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  I just use this. There is a space between the # and the %%.  For newbies it might help to add that the first code block goes to ~/.config/nvim/after/queries/python/textobjects.scm file. I added a line ; extends at the top and viola!

Answer (score 0):

The following is a nice setup to work with jupyter cells in "percent" format in neovim:

1. Use a query to find the cell marker (add this to textobjects.scm):

```lisp
(module
 (comment) @cell.comment
 (#lua-match? @cell.comment "^# %%%%"))
```

2. To get next/prev key-mappings you can install the [nvim-treesitter-textobjects](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects) plugin and configure its move capability to map your desired keystrokes to this @cell.comment capture.

```lua
textobjects = {
  move = {
    enable = true,
    goto_next_start = {
      ["]j"] = { query = "@cell.comment", desc = "Next cell start" },
    },
    goto_previous_start = {
      ["[j"] = { query = "@cell.comment", desc = "Prev cell start" },
    },
  },
```

3. Create two key Mappings:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("x", "aj", ":<c-u>normal ]j[jV]j<cr>")
vim.keymap.set("o", "aj", ":<c-u>normal ]j[jV]j<cr>")
vim.keymap.set("x", "ij", ":<c-u>normal ]j[jjV]jk<cr>")
vim.keymap.set("o", "ij", ":<c-u>normal ]j[jjV]jk<cr>")
```

4. Bonus: add the following to injections.scm to enable markdown formatting for markdown cells.

```lisp
((
  (comment) @_mdcomment
  . (expression_statement 
      (string (string_content) @injection.content)))
  (#set! injection.language "markdown")
  (#lua-match? @_mdcomment "^# %%%% %[markdown%]"))
```

=================

If you want to use textobjects to query the entire cell contents, the following does the job. Note that this slows down your neovim's navigation:

```lisp
(module
 (comment) @cell.start
 (#lua-match? @cell.start "^# %%%%")
 .
 (_)+ @cell.content
 (#not-any-lua-match? @cell.content "^# %%%%")
 .
 (comment)? @cell.end
 (#lua-match? @cell.end "^# %%%%")
 (#make-range! "cell.outer" @cell.start @cell.content)
)
```

Then use `cell.outer` in your `select` config of nvim textobjects plugin

Comment: For this to work nicely the last cell should have and end marker too